# Replace `set` statements to `setx` in a batch script using powershell

Tags: powershell

Using powershell, I want to take a `.bat` file and replace all lines in which `set` is called to set an environment variable and change it to a corresponding `setx` call. Unfortunately it's not as simple as just doing a search and replace on the file, replacing `set` for `setx`, because the syntax is diffferent: `set ENVNAME=abc` vs `setx ENVNAME abc`.

Is there a simple way to do this in powershell? To just do the `set` for `setx` replacement, I have:

```
(Get-Content $orig_filename ) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace "set", "setx"} | Set-Content $new_filename
```

Any pointers for a powershell novice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Did some pretty limited testing and I'm not sure what your bat file looks like, but this may work for you.

```
(Get-Content $orig_filename ) | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'set (.*)\=(.*)','setx $1 $2'
} | Set-Content $new_filename
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also just chain another `-replace` to do the work for you. Also made the set > setx replacement a little more less error prone by ensuring you are replacing the word set at the beginning of the string. Since `-replace` functions as an array operator you do not *need* the foreach loop.

```
(Get-Content $orig_filename ) -replace "^set\b", "setx" -replace "="," " | Set-Content $new_filename
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Realizing what I want to do is a bit more complicated because I also need to account for translating `set ABC=` (to unset) to `setx ABC ""`. Thinking maybe a different strategy might be easier, but still need to figure it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406439/powershell-check-what-environment-variables-have-changed