# Powershell check what environment variables have changed

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get a copy of all of the current environment variables in powershell? What I want to do is get a copy of `$env` at a particular point in time, run a batch script that does a bunch of `set` commands, and then look at `$env` again and check what has changed. I would then determine which environment variables had been newly set, changed or unset, and then run the appropriate `setx` commands (or `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($NAME, $value, 'User')`), to make the things that have changed in-process to persistent user changes.

I've tried calling `.clone()` on `$env`, but that didn't work. Any ideas on how to get a copy of `$env` or general ideas about how to accomplish what I describe above? Suggestions for a powershell newbie would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the items in the `env:` drive?

Comment: How do you make a copy of `env:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just retrieve the `Env:` drive into a variable.

```
$envVars = Get-ChildItem Env:
```

I wrote some functions that might be of use to you as well, in this article:

[Windows IT Pro: Take Charge of Environment Variables in PowerShell](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/take-charge-environment-variables-powershell)

I presented some functions in the article: `Get-Environment` (same as `Get-ChildItem Env:`, but included for completeness), `Restore-Environment` (restores a saved copy of the environment), and `Invoke-CmdScript` (runs a `cmd.exe` shell script [batch file] that adds environment variables and makes them available in PowerShell).

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more appropriate way to do it but this should work.

```
$a = @{}
Get-ChildItem env: | % { $a[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
```